# jQuery hoverIntent Not Firing if mouse is already over the element on document ready

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I am using the jQuery plug-in hoverIntent.  The problem is sometimes when the page is loaded, the mouse is already over the object '#gallery', and will therefore not trigger the hoverIntent code.

Here is an example of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#gallery').hoverIntent(function(){
    $('.gallery-thumbs').stop().animate({'height': '65px'},400); //in code animating a element child within #gallery
  },function(){
    $('.gallery-thumbs').stop().animate({'height': '33px'}); //out code animating a child element within #gallery
  });
});
```

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Comment: Do you really need to use that plugin? It seems only thing it does is  'it waits until the user's mouse slows down enough before making the call'. Its basically a .hover event with a timeout.

Also I think other jquery events wont fire when mouse is over the element on pageload before jquery is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I would suggest if you want to keep using this library is catching the first (and only the first, with `one`) mousemove event and check if the mouse is over the #gallery at this time.

You can check if an event is over an object by using this :

```
var eventIsOver = function(event, o) {
    if ((!o) || o==null) return false;
    var pos = o.offset();
    var ex = event.pageX;
    var ey = event.pageY;
    if (
        ex>=pos.left
        && ex<=pos.left+o.width()
        && ey>=pos.top
        && ey<=pos.top+o.height()
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').one('mousemove', function(e) {
     if (eventIsOver(e, $('#gallery')) {
         // do what you want to do if the mouse is on the gallery initially
     }
  });
  $('#gallery').hoverIntent(function(){
    $('.gallery-thumbs').stop().animate({'height': '65px'},400); //in code animating a element child within #gallery
  },function(){
    $('.gallery-thumbs').stop().animate({'height': '33px'}); //out code animating a child element within #gallery
  });
});
```

Comment: How would I use this code?  Where would I pass the element name?

Comment: o is the element, for example $('#gallery').

Comment: I feel kind of dumb, but I can't figure out how to implement your code. How would I implement this code? like:
eventIsOver($('#gallery'));
???

Comment: I edited to explain the details I had left aside the first time

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).one("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (mouse pointer is on gallery) {
            $('.gallery-thumbs').stop().animate({'height': '65px'}, 400);
        }
    });

    $('#gallery').hoverIntent(function() {
        $('.gallery-thumbs').stop().animate({'height': '65px'}, 400); //in code animating a element child within #gallery
    },function() {
        $('.gallery-thumbs').stop().animate({'height': '33px'}); //out code animating a child element within #gallery
    });
});
```

Comment: yes I think this is what I am looking for, now I need to figure out the "mouse pointer is on gallery" part

Answer (score 0):

I gave up with a perfect solution and setted for triggering mouseenter on a child element within #gallery

```
$('.gallery-nav').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#gallery').trigger("mouseenter");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking another solution, here's mine:

```
$('myselector').hoverIntent({
  over: myOverfunc,
  out: myOutfunc
});

$('myselector').trigger('mouseenter.hoverIntent');
```

Pay attention to the 'mouseenter.hoverIntent' as it is the event registered by the plugin (tested on r7).

Answer (score 0):

It has some issue due to some bug in there js,

I have already done all hard work. you just need to add option

I have solved it. you can get js from here.
and when you are calling slimscroll function add below option

> mouseOver:true

As demo

```
jQuery('#scroll').slimScroll({
       height: jQuery(window).height()+'px',
        railVisible: true,
        allowPageScroll: true,
        mouseOver:true
    });
```

[Visit Link / Download Here](https://github.com/nil4you/jQuery-slimScroll)